# What's wrong with my C++ variable(scope related)?

Tags: c++, grid, coordinates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0, y = 1, k = 5;
{       
    int x = 1;
    x = 10;
    cout << "x is " << x << ", y is " << y << endl;     
}
cout << "x is " << x << " and k is " << k << endl;

cout << endl;
cout << endl;
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    {
        int y = 7;
        x = 2;
    }
    cout << "(x, y) is : (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
}


cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

x is 10, y is 1

x is 0 and k is 5

(x, y) is : (2, 6)

I think (x,y) should be (5,6). Because that's the coordinates x and y are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying `x` from the outer scope here:

```
{
    int y = 7; // local variable
    x = 2;     // variable from outer scope
}
```

If you had said `int x = 2;` then you could expect to get `(5,6)`. But you didn't.

Comment: Then the second line printed out should be x is 10 and k is 5

Comment: @James No, you have `int x = 1;` before `x = 10;`.

Comment: So you mean x=10 here only changes the local variable x, which was 1. But x=10 does not change the initial x=0?

Comment: redefining x gives you a new x inside that particular scope. That inner x is ten, then vanishes leaving only the original x

Comment: @James Yes, that's how lexical scope works. It becomes more obvious if you use different types. If you say `int x = 0; {std::string x = "1"; x = 2;}` the compiler will complain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned value 2 to x in last scope hence  it's (2,6).

Answer (score -2):

Not how it works, because the variable `x` from the outer scope was the one you changed in the inner scope, where there is no other x to hide it.  Consider this example of why this is necessary:

```
static const size_t N = 10;
size_t i = 0;
int array[N];

while (i < 10) {
  const int x = i*i;
  array[i] = x;
  ++i;
} // We're out of the block where i was incremented.  Should this be an infinite loop?

// Should array be uninitialized because this is the scope it was in and we updated it in a nested scope?
```